# Adding ArcGIS-FeatureServer-Layer to QGIS using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, arcgis-server, qgis-2, feature-service

I have a password protected **ArcGIS-FeatureServer** Service, the service provides 25 layers.

Using "Add Layer --> Add ArcGIS-FeatureServer-Layer" works like it should.

Is there any way to add these kind of layers with PyQGIS? I could not find a documentation or example anywhere.

How to Add a normal WFS layer with PyQGIS is well documented.

For **ArcGIS MapServer** it is super-easy:

```
iface.addRasterLayer("url='my_featuere_layer_url' layer='0'", "mylayer", "arcgismapserver")
```

But the provider "arcgismapserver" is not documented anywhere, just found an example after some search, so I expect that there is a similar solution for ArcGIS-FeatureServer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all, the answer is quite simple (but nowhere documented):

```
uri = "crs='EPSG:25832' filter='' url='http://someurl.com/featureserver' table="" sql="
my_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layername", "arcgisfeatureserver")
```

The lack of documentation leads to a lot of other questions (bounding-box, username, password, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [ArcGISConnector-QGIS-Plugin](https://github.com/geometalab/ArcGISConnector-QGIS-Plugin/blob/master/connector.py) connector.py file.  Looks like it requests the features service as json using the requests module.

Comment: Thx, already checked that out, but hoping for an easier solution and it seems to be a very complicated solution. For ArcGIS MapServer it is super-easy, therefore I assume a similar solution for ArcGIS FeatureServer, it is just not documented.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't find any decent documentation ([issue 40406](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40406)).

Scanning [qgsafsprovider.cpp](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/arcgisrest/qgsafsprovider.cpp) gives some clues.

Note 'filter' doesn't seem to be working ([issue 27635](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/27635))