# Connecting QGIS to table hosted on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server

I have some aspatial tables hosted on ArcGIS Server (10.3.1 with Oracle 11g for the database) that I would like to load into QGIS (2.18).

The Add ArcGisFeatureServer dialog is only displaying the feature layers i.e. the tables are not listed.

Is there any functionality built-in to QGIS or available via a common plugin that allows me to load these tables?

---

As suggested by Francisco Raga in the comments below I have tried loading the table via the python API.

While this loads the spatial layer at index 0 of the Feature Server:

```
iface.addVectorLayer("url='https://example.com/.../FeatureServer/0' crs='EPSG:4326'", "title", "arcgisfeatureserver")
```

Both of these attempts to load the data table at index 1 produce only an "invalid layer" message:

```
iface.addVectorLayer("url='https://example.com/.../FeatureServer/1' crs='EPSG:4326'", "title", "arcgisfeatureserver")    
iface.addVectorLayer("url='https://example.com/.../FeatureServer/1'", "title", "arcgisfeatureserver")
```

Comment: Try using Python ,https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/261753/49538

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto we are using Oracle 11g

Comment: @FranciscoRaga Thanks for tip, unfortunately I haven't found any success.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to an Oracle Database using Layer>Add Layer> Add Oracle Spatial Layer.

[image]

This can list both spatial and non-spatial tables in the database. It since you are not using Oracle Spatial (ArcGIS server) the spatial tables will probably not work directly, but the non-spatial tables should.