# ArcGIS FeatureServer in QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Can someone tell me how to add a ArcGIS FeatureServer to a QGIS plugin? I've found a post here on how to add maplayers which is simple enough but I can't find an description on how to do the same for FeatureServer layers. I'm trying to build a plugin to load a large number of various WMS, WFS, maplayer, featureserver datasets in QGIS without having to manually load them.

example:
https://services2.arcgis.com/chCSiGO4ORzXeSGk/arcgis/rest/services/Archeologie__Onderzoeken/FeatureServer

maplayer syntax that works:

```
iface.addRasterLayer("url='my_featuere_layer_url' layer='0'", "mylayer", "arcgismapserver")
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259897/adding-arcgis-featureserver-layer-to-qgis-using-pyqgis

Comment: can you explain the difference?

Comment: The question is basically the same, the solution provided doesn't work for the current version of Qgis so I made my own post. If that's not what should be done please ignore me flagging the post. I've tried the solution provided (uri = "crs='EPSG:25832' filter='' url='http://someurl.com/featureserver' table="" sql="
my_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layername", "arcgisfeatureserver") but that doesn't work so I posted this in the hope of getting some help. I'm a complete newbie in creating plugins, python and programming in general so this forum is my lifeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the correct uri you can load the layer manually in QGIS 3 in the **browser window / ArcGISFeatureServer** and than look at the layer properties on information tab, there is the source written.

In your example you have to set the layernumber

```
uri="crs='EPSG:28992' url='https://services2.arcgis.com/chCSiGO4ORzXeSGk/arcgis/rest/services/Archeologie__Onderzoeken/FeatureServer/0'"
my_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layername", "arcgisfeatureserver")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(my_layer)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks for the clarification.