# Unable to get shape data from ArcGIS REST API

Tags: python, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to download hurricane data from ArcGIS.  There are two things I can do.

1. I can go to their web interface at
   https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/ArcGIS/rest/services/Active_Hurricanes_v1/FeatureServer/1/query
   Set a few values ('Where' field I set to 1=1, 'Out Fields' I set to *)
   Then scroll to the bottom and click the "Query(GET)" button.  Some values come up on the screen.
   All Good, but no shape data.
2. I can use Python (this is my real goal).
   I have a script to do this.

---

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import json



url_json= 'https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/ArcGIS/rest/services/Active_Hurricanes_v1/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pjson&token='    

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_json) 

webContent = response.read()  # byte string of the JSON result

jsonContent = json.loads(webContent)  # create a JSON object from the byte string

for object in jsonContent['features']:
    rec = {}  # create an empty dictionary for each feature 

    for k in object['attributes'].keys():
        rec[k] = object['attributes'][k]
```

To get the url I used in the python program, I just pressed the button on (1) and then used the info in the url bar.  Only difference is I selected json instead of html for output.

Problem: I can't figure out how to get it to return the blob for the shape info.

Does his API permit that?

If so, what do I do to in the query window and in the url to get it?

Comment: You will likely need a python rest api library. example: https://pypi.org/project/bmi-arcgis-restapi/

Comment: That query doesn't return any geometry, because you specified `returnGeometry=false`

Comment: I was unclear.  I tried that switch, but it only returns a single point and not the polygon I expected.  I think this particular service only is intended to return individual points and not polygons.  Still looking at the relation between the different services, but I think that's what's going on.

Comment: Using the rest API would be a third way and that link is particularly useful, even though it doesn't immediately yield what I was expecting.

Comment: the URL you give get to : "Home > services > Active_Hurricanes_v1 (FeatureServer) > Observed Position > query" where "Observed Position" is a point layer so it's expected to get point geometry rather than polygon. Are you sure this is the layer you want to query ? That being said if I query a polygon layer (the Forecast Error Cone for exemple) with the 
 return geometry set to true and the format as geojson I get a geojson with polygon geometry as expected

Answer (score 1):

A non python rather simple yet manual way

You can use QGIS to download the data using this the ArcGIS online rest url you provided https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/ArcGIS/rest/services/
[image: Right click on ARCGIS Feature server]
Select New Connection
[image: paste the URL]

Find the data you need and right-click export layer to file and choose shp or geopackage.
[[image: export layer to file3]

Extending this concept you can use pyqgis to automate this:
[Adding ArcGIS-FeatureServer-Layer to QGIS using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259897/adding-arcgis-featureserver-layer-to-qgis-using-pyqgis)

Comment: This the way, normally this is the quickest route, but I think that @elbillaf is looking for a way in python to do this.

Answer (score 0):

As this is too long for the comments...

Using this url for all the points in **GeoJSON**:
`https://services9.arcgis.com/RHVPKKiFTONKtxq3/ArcGIS/rest/services/Active_Hurricanes_v1/FeatureServer/1/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=0.0&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&returnGeodetic=false&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&featureEncoding=esriDefault&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&datumTransformation=&applyVCSProjection=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnUniqueIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnQueryGeometry=false&returnDistinctValues=false&cacheHint=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&having=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=true&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pgeojson&token=`

Response:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection", 
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature", 
      "geometry" : 
      {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
          168.300000000745, -12
        ]
      }, 
      "properties" : {
        "STORMNAME" : "Yasa"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "type" : "Feature", 
      "geometry" : 
      {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
          168.60000000149, -12.1999999992549
        ]
      }, 
      "properties" : {
        "STORMNAME" : "Yasa"
      }
    }, 
    {
      "type" : "Feature", 
      "geometry" : 
      {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
          168.800000000745, -12.3999999985099
        ]
      }, 
      "properties" : {
        "STORMNAME" : "Yasa"
      }
    },
```

Comment: I'm about to knockoff for the evening and I have a few things I have to take care of in the morning, but I'll get back to this and try that. tx