# Download GIS shapefiles from Geo Portal

Tags: shapefile, geolocation, download, geoportal

I was wondering if there are any ways to download or extract the GIS information from a geo portal, i.e., all schools' geolocation from https://schoolgis.nic.in/

Comment: There's quite a bit of variability in portals, so it would depend on the portal. What have you tried? In general, shapefile is an *awful* export format, since it destroys data natively maintained in better formats.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368774/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379236/88814

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rest end point:

> `https://geoportal.nic.in/nicgis/rest/services/`

There are quite a number of Schools (1.4 million)

Even with using a strong internet connection it takes time to retrieve from this service. Have patience.
[image]

Comment: Could you show the steps that you have done in QGIS please? Thanks!

Comment: Add the above url like this example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382142/unable-to-get-shape-data-from-arcgis-rest-api/382151#382151

Comment: Very helpful. Appreciate it